# playframework 1.2.4 invoke action in jquery with render on a view

Tags: jquery, ajax, groovy, rendering, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to mutualize an html view between two controllers Entity and EntityGlobal.

The Entity controller method show :

```java
public static void show(String id) {
    Object entity = entityService(id);
    renderTemplate("@detailEntity", entity);
}
```

The EntityGlobal controller method show :

```java
public static void show(String id) {
    Object entity = globalEntityService(id);
    renderTemplate("@detailEntity", entity);
}
```

**The actual situation :**

View list.html of Entity controller :

```html
...
<table>
#{list entities, as:'entity'}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="@{Entity.show(entity.id)}">entity.name</a></td>
    ...
    </tr>
#{/list}
</table>
...
```

View list.html of EntityGlobal controller :

```html
...
<table>
#{list entities, as:'entity'}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="@{EntityGlobal.show(entity.id)}">entity.name</a></td>
    ...
    </tr>
#{/list}
</table>
...
```

All the code is duplicated except the line :

```html
<a href="@{EntityGlobal.show(entity.id)}">
```

**I'm trying to have something like that :**

Generic template view listTemplate.html :

```html
...
<table>
#{list entities, as:'entity'}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:show('${entity.id}');">entity.name</a></td>
    ...
    </tr>
#{/list}
</table>
...
```

View list.html of Entity controller :

```html
#{include 'listTemplate.html' /}
<script>
    var showEntity = #{jsAction @Entity.show(':entityId') /};
    function show(entityId) {
        $.get(showEntity({entityId: entityId}), function() {console.log("entity SUCCESS");});
    }
</script>
```

View list.html of EntityGlobal controller :

```html
#{include 'listTemplate.html' /}
<script>
    var showEntity = #{jsAction @EntityGlobal.show(':entityId') /};
    function show(entityId) {
        $.get(showEntity({entityId: entityId}), function() {console.log("entity global SUCCESS");});
    }
</script>
```

It doesn't work. When i click on a link, the method @EntityGlobal.show(':entityId') is called, the message of the console.log si printed but the render on the view 'detailEntity' is not made.

Is it possible to call an action play in jquery and load the template ? 
If someone knows a way to do it, it would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The work around I found using playframework tags :

The tag tag_list.html :

```html
<table>
#{list _entities, as:'entity'}
    %{ _entityShow = _entityShow.toString().replace(":entityId", entity.id); %}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="${_entityShow}">entity.name</a></td>
    ...
    </tr>
#{/list}
</table>
```

View list.html of Entity controller :

```html
#{tag_list entityShow:@Entity.show(':entityId'), entities: entities /}
```

View list.html of EntityGlobal controller :

```html
#{tag_list entityShow:@EntityGlobal.show(':entityId'), entities: entities /}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var showEntityUrl = '@@{EntityGlobal.show(entity.id)}';
    window.location = showEntityUrl;
</script>
```